How to make a responsive side nav like Gmail with Bootstrap 5?
How can I make my side menu in a Blazor Server application (.net 6 Blazor Server) like Gmail's left menu, where only icons are displayed at first, and hovering on the menu expands the menu and displays names, without narrowing the main body section? I have included my current menu and CSS files.
Here is my current menu:
Left Nav menu
Here is the NavMenu.razor:
<main class="sidebarmain">
    
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 p-3" style="width: 280px;">
        <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
            <svg class="bi me-2" width="30" height="24">
                <use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use>
            </svg>
            @*<span class="fs-5 fw-semibold">Collapsible</span>*@
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
            <li class="mb-1">
                <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                    Home
                </button>
                <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                        @* <li>
                            <a href="/" class="link-dark rounded">Dashboard</a>
                        </li> *@
                        <li>
                            <NavLink href="/" class="link-dark rounded">Dashboard</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="mb-1">
                <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    Orders
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse" style="">
                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                        @* <li>
                            <a href="/orders" class="link-dark rounded">Order List</a>
                        </li> *@
                        <li>
                            <NavLink href="/orderlist" class="link-dark rounded" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">Order List</NavLink>
                        </li>
                        @* <li>
                            <a href="/upload" class="link-dark rounded">File Upload/Download</a>
                        </li> *@
                        <li>
                            <NavLink href="/upload" class="link-dark rounded" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">File Upload/Download</NavLink>
                        </li>
                       @*  <li>
                            <a href="/report" class="link-dark rounded">Report</a>
                        </li> *@
                        <li>
                            <NavLink href="/report" class="link-dark rounded" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">Report</NavLink>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="mb-1">
                <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#vendors-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    Vendors
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="vendors-collapse">
                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/vendors" class="link-dark rounded">Vendor Management</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="mb-1">
                <button class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#customers-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    Customers
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="customers-collapse">
                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/customers" class="link-dark rounded">Customer Management</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <AuthorizeView Roles="Administrators">
                <li class="border-top my-3" id="admin"></li>
            <li class="mb-1">
                <button id="administrator" class="btn btn-toggle align-items-center rounded collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    Administration
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/administration" class="link-dark rounded">User Management</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                                <a href="/warehouseaddress" class="link-dark rounded">Warehouse Management</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            </AuthorizeView>
        </ul>
    </div>
</main>

Here is the MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<PageTitle>Vorlance</PageTitle>
<style>
    .pb-3,
    .py-3 {
        padding-bottom: 0.93rem !important;
    }
</style>
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar @NavMenuCssClass">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid toggler-container">
                <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <span class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
                    <img src="/css/images/logo.png" alt="" width="220" height="73" >
                </span>
                
            </div> 
            @*<a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>*@
            <LoginDisplay/>
         
        </div>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
            <RadzenDialog />
            <RadzenNotification/>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;
    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;
    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}

Here is the sidebar.css:
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
/*main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}*/
.sidebarmain {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100vh;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #ced0da !important;
}
.b-example-divider {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.bi {
  vertical-align: -.125em;
  pointer-events: none;
  fill: currentColor;
}
.dropdown-toggle { outline: 0; }
.nav-flush .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-toggle {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .65);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
.btn-toggle:hover,
.btn-toggle:focus {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
  background-color: #679fd2;
}
#administrator:hover, #administrator:focus {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.btn-toggle::before {
  width: 1.25em;
  line-height: 0;
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='rgba%280,0,0,.5%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M5 14l6-6-6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  transition: transform .35s ease;
  transform-origin: .5em 50%;
}
.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .85);
}
.btn-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.btn-toggle-nav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: .1875rem .5rem;
  margin-top: .125rem;
  margin-left: 1.25rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-toggle-nav a:hover,
.btn-toggle-nav a:focus {
  background-color: #98dbe8;
}
.scrollarea {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.fw-semibold { font-weight: 600; }
.lh-tight { line-height: 1.25; }
#admin {
    border-top: 0.1rem solid white !important;
}

Here is the Gmail left menu that I want to do it with Bootstrap 5:
Gmail left Menu
Update:
I could display the icons at first but I couldn't manage to expand the sidebar over the main area.
Sidebar only icons at first
Here is the added CSS:
/* Sidebar */

.sidebar {
    position: fixed; /* Make the sidebar fixed */
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0;
    height: 100% !important; /* Full height */
    z-index: 100 !important; /* Ensure it is above other content */
    background-color: #ced0da; /* Background color */
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

/* Initial state: only icons are visible */

.sidebar.collapsed {
    width: 45px; /* Adjust width as needed */
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

.sidebar.collapsed a {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.sidebar.collapsed a span {
    display: none;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.sidebar.collapsed a i {
    
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    margin-left: -27px !important; /* Move the icon more to the left */
}


/* Expanded state: icons and text are visible */

.sidebar.expanded {
    width: 250px; /* Adjust width as needed */
    transition: width 0.3s;
}

.sidebar.expanded a {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.sidebar.expanded a span {
    display: none;
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.sidebar.expanded a i {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    margin-left: -27px !important; /* Move the icon more to the left */
}

.sidebar:hover {
    width: 250px; /* Adjust width as needed */
}


"without narrowing the main body section" - you'll want your side menu to be absolute or fixed positioned to begin with, so that when it extends in width, it will extend over the content next to it, instead of moving it.

@C3roe thank you, I am not good at CSS. How can I where only icons are displayed at first, and expanding the menu displays names? Could you please guide me?

you might use ::before and/or ::after along with :hover selector in CSS to do something like that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover

@C3roe Could you please check my update? I could display the icons at first but I couldn't manage to expand the sidebar over the main area.

Let me tell you how I succeeded, maybe someone will need it.
First I changed my NavMenu.razor to this:
<div class="sBar">
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0 mt-5">


        <li>
            <a href="/" class="link-dark rounded">
                <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="/orderlist" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                <i class="fas fa-list"></i> <span>Order List</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/upload" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
                <i class="fas fa-upload"></i> <span>File Upload/Download</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="/report" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <i class="fas fa-chart-bar"></i> <span>Report</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li>

            <a href="/vendors" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex">
                <i class="fas fa-industry"></i> <span>Vendor Management</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <li>
            <a href="/customers" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i> <span>Customer Management</span>
            </a>
        </li>


        <AuthorizeView Roles="Administrators">

            <li>
                <a href="/administration" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i> <span>User Management</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/warehouseaddress" class="link-dark rounded nav-link-flex">
                    <i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i> <span>Warehouse Management</span>
                </a>
            </li>


        </AuthorizeView>
    </ul>
</div>


@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapsed" : "expanded";

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    private void ExpandNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = false;
    }

    private void CollapseNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = true;
    }

}

Then I changed Mainlayout.razor to this:
<style>
    .pb-3,
    .py-3 {
        padding-bottom: 0.93rem !important;
    }
    
</style>
<div class="page">
    <div>
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main style="border-left-style: solid;border-left-width: 45px;">
        <div class="top-row px-1 auth navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <span class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">
                    <img src="/css/images/logo.png" alt="" width="220" height="73" >
                </span>
                
            </div> 
            
            <LoginDisplay/>
         
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
            <RadzenDialog />
            <RadzenNotification/>
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

And finally used this CSS for the sidebar:
.sBar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    background-color: #ced0da;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
   
}

.sBar:hover {
    width: 250px;
}

.sBar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0; /* Top margin */
    margin-right: 0; /* Right margin */
    margin-bottom: 0; /* Bottom margin */
    margin-left: 0; /* Left margin */
}

.sBar ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.sBar ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sBar ul li span {
    display: none;
}

.sBar ul li:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
    
}

.sBar:hover a {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.sBar:hover a span{
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
}

.sBar:hover a i {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
    margin-left: -1px !important; /* Move the icon more to the left */
}

